# RSpec - Check if method was called further down(up?) the call stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I've been using built-in Rails testing suite and am now moving into RSpec for testing. I'm trying to figure out to test if a method was called in the midst of calling another method.
For example, my update_service.call method gets called with an object. The update_service calls the manage_service.call method. I'm trying to test that the manage_service.call method was ever called.

```
expect(@update_service).to receive(:call).with(object).at_least(:once)
expect(@manage_service).to receive(:call).with(object.id).at_least(:once)

@update_service.call(encounter)
```

With this setup, I get the following failure:

```
    Failures:

  1) UpdateService should call manage_service
     Failure/Error: expect(@manage_service).to receive(:call).with(object.id).at_least(:once)
     
       (#<ManageService:0x00007ffaf8c76190 @sdi=ServiceDI>).call(1)
           expected: at least 1 time with arguments: (1)
           received: 0 times
        # ....
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec allows you to use the `any_instance_of` set of matchers for setting this up.
This can be useful if you need to do this particular type of test and can't manually specify the instances via DI.

`expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).and_return("Wobble")`

See [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

Comment: Additionally you don't need to specify a value if you don't want to rather the original implementation can be called by `.and_call_original`